# Xdebug doesn't write to log file

Tags: xdebug

**Ubuntu 18.04**

I'm setting up Xdebug with Sublime Text 3.1.1. I'm trying to organize breakpoints for PHP 7.2.

I removed the log file. It existed. I looked into it, decided that it needs cleaning. Then I just did

```
sudo rm xdebug.log
```

Then I run in Sublime Text: Tools / Xdebug / Start debugging (launch browser).

Well, the file doesn't appear. Then I started debugging several times and at least Xdebug wrote something to the log.

Could you tell me whether Xdebug writes something to the log file every time I start debugging or not? If not, what are the conditions of writing to log?

**php.ini**

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.idekey="sublime.xdebug"
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_log = "/var/log/xdebug.log"
```

**phpinfo()**

```
xdebug

xdebug support => enabled
Version => 2.6.1
IDE Key => sublime.xdebug

Supported protocols
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.extended_info => On => On
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.filename_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name => gcstats.%p => gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => sublime.xdebug => sublime.xdebug
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump => 2 => 2
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_autostart => On => On
xdebug.remote_connect_back => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => localhost => localhost
xdebug.remote_log => /var/log/xdebug.log => /var/log/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
xdebug.remote_timeout => 200 => 200
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

Comment: When Xdebug sees "debug me" flag (e.g. cookie or GET/POST parameter) or it is configured to debug every single script (with `remote_autostart = 1`) then it write into the log where it connects to, the outcome (even for unsuccessful session) and actual communication with debug client (received and sent data). For that `remote_log` must point to a accessible location with write permission.